# Funky flexbox heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

That's a pretty simple structure which I can not achieve using flexbox.

I have a header and a body elements within the body I have a long (in height) element and after that I have a small footer within the body. I want the content to be scrollable and the footer always visible.

I set everything to use flexbox and I use `flex-direction: column` to achieve vertical positioning as well as `flex: 1` to occupy remaining space with elements with undefined height.

Weirdly enough, my header with fixed height of 50 pixels is only 20 pixels high and the content is not scrollable at all, or rather it is but along with the little footer (in green) which is not what I want...

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1zxewaey/)

```css
.flex { display: flex; }
.flex1 { flex: 1; }
.col { flex-direction: column; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.pad { padding: 10px 15px; }
.h50 { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="flex col" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="red h50">
    Wtf?
  </div>
  <div class="blue flex1 pad">
    <div class="flex col" style="height: 100%">
      <div class="yellow flex1" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div style="height: 1500px">
          Long content here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green h50">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining Flexbox with inner elements using height with percent is not a good idea, as it will create issues cross browsers.

Use Flexbox all the way, here by updating these 2 elements classes, where I removed `height: 100%` and added `flex` to the `blue` so its child will fill its parent height, and `flex1` to the child so it will fill its parent width.

```
  <div class="blue flex1 pad flex">
    <div class="flex flex1 col">
```

*Also added `margin: 0` to the `body`*

Stack snippet

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.flex { display: flex; }
.flex1 { flex: 1; }
.col { flex-direction: column; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.pad { padding: 10px 15px; }
.h50 { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="flex col" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="red h50">
    Wtf?
  </div>
  <div class="blue flex1 pad flex">
    <div class="flex flex1 col">
      <div class="yellow flex1" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div style="height: 1500px">
          Long content here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green h50">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment, where Firefox appear to need `min-height: 0` on the `blue` element.

*For flex items, their default `min-height/width` value is `auto`, which prevent them from shrinking below their content's size, so changing to `0` solves that.*

Stack snippet

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.flex { display: flex; }
.flex1 { flex: 1; }
.col { flex-direction: column; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.pad { padding: 10px 15px; }
.h50 { height: 50px; }
.mh  { min-height: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="flex col" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="red h50">
    Wtf?
  </div>
  <div class="blue flex1 pad flex mh">
    <div class="flex flex1 col">
      <div class="yellow flex1" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div style="height: 1500px">
          Long content here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green h50">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's still the same result, everything is scrollable the header and footer should be static and only the yellow area should be scrollable

Comment: @php_nub_qq In the above snippet the yellow scroll within the viewport (am using Chrome btw), so how is it the same for you?

Comment: Oh so it's a browser issue, I'm using firefox... But also in chromium is the same, not working.. jesus

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zxewaey/1/ open it in firefox and you will see :(

Comment: @php_nub_qq FF appear to want `min-height: 0` to work: https://jsfiddle.net/1zxewaey/2/ ..... updated my answer

Comment: @php_nub_qq Thank you :) ... and noticed the `min-height` only need to be on the blue elements, so updated with that change

Comment: But how did you figure out that it needs min-height? It's not documented anywhere, or is it?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Have some practice :) ... and the one property that often cause similar issue in other situations is the `min-height` (or `min-width`), which defaults to `auto` for flex items, and with that don't want to shrink below its contents size